# How to find mutually absolutely continuous measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is as follows :
Let μ be a σ-finite measure on (X,M). Then there exists a finite measure ν on (X,M) such that μ and ν are mutually absolutely continuous ; that is μ<<ν and ν<<μ

I am not sure how to even start the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Let $E_j$ be a collection of finite measure sets covering your space $X$. Consider a modification of $\mu$ on these sets (or a mutually disjoint version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you let $\nu = D \: d\mu$ where $D: X \rightarrow \left (0,\infty \right]$ is an element of $L^1(\mu)$ then this will be true. So if you can prove that such a function exists for $\mu \; \sigma$-finite then you have solved the problem.

Comment: So its basically an application of the Radon-Nikodym theorem ?

Comment: No it is in reverse of the R-N theorem.  Knowing the R-N theorem suggests to consider a measure of the form $D\;d\mu$.

Comment: I'll just add it's much simpler than R-N.

Comment: Why does D have to be non negative?Also, assuming two measures are each absolutely continuous in respect to a third measure, will they be mutually absolutely continuous? Did you rather mean $d\nu=Dd\mu$?